# Produce the nth lexicographic permutation of a string consisting of letters H and V

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, combinatorics

I have tried many possible methods here but I am still not able to reduce the time complexity of below algorithm.

```
//This function returns the next lexicographical permutation of the StringBuilder s
static StringBuilder getKRankString(StringBuilder s)
{
    char ch[] = (s.toString()).toCharArray();      
    int i = 0, j=0;
    //This loop gets the highest i for which ch[i]<ch[i+1]
    for(int k=0;k<s.length()-2;k++){
        if(ch[s.length()-2-k]<ch[s.length()-1-k]){
            i = s.length()-2-k;
            break;
        }

    }
    //System.out.println(i);
    //This loop gets the highest j for which ch[j]>ch[i]
    for(int k=s.length()-1;k>i;k--){
        if(ch[k]>ch[i]){
            j = k;
            break;
        }

    }
    //System.out.println(j);
    //swap characters at i and j
    char temp = ch[i];
    ch[i] = ch[j];
    ch[j] = temp;
    //Append the original string till i to reversed string from i till end
    StringBuilder swapped = new StringBuilder(new String(ch));
    //System.out.println(swapped);
    String sb1 = swapped.substring(0, i+1);
    String sb2 = (new StringBuilder(swapped.substring(i+1, s.length())).reverse()).toString();
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(sb1+sb2);
    return str;   
}    

static String[] gridLand(String[] inp) {
    String[] outputArr = new String[inp.length];
    for(int i=0;i<inp.length;i++){
    //get the first line of input and get integer x and y
        int x = Integer.valueOf(inp[i].split(" ")[0]);
        int y = Integer.valueOf(inp[i].split(" ")[1]);
        int k = Integer.valueOf(inp[i].split(" ")[2]);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //form the original string using x H's and y V's.
    //This will be the first String of this order
        for(int j = 0; j < x; j++)
            sb = sb.append("H");
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            sb = sb.append("V");
        //String s1 = sb.toString();
    //run the below functoin K times to get Kth lexicographical string
        for(int m = 0; m < k; m++)
            sb = getKRankString(sb);
        outputArr[i] = sb.toString();
    }
    return outputArr;

}⁠⁠⁠⁠
```

The basic layout of my problem is as follows:
I have a string that is composed of only H's and V's. There can be not more than 10 H's and 10 V's possible. I need to find the Kth lexicographical order of such pattern. Also, inp[] array contains input is format:

```
2 2 3
4 5 4
```

which means that total H = 2, total V = 2 and I need to print 3rd lexicographical permutation of HHVV.
Similarly for 4 5 4, I need to print 4th lexicographical permutation of HHHHVVVVV.

Comment: For an algorithm that has a complexity linear to the length of the string, see the last part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230266/how-to-calculate-the-lexicographical-rank-of-a-given-permutation/34235272#34235272

Answer (score 1):

Let `P(n,m)` be the number of permutations of `n` Hs and `m` Vs.  For `m>0` and `n>0`, `P(n,m) = (n + m)!/(n! * m!)`.

Let's say you want the `k`th permutation of `n` Hs and `m` Vs:

If `k <= P(n-1,m)`, then the answer is an H followed by the `k`th permutation of `n-1` Hs and `m` Vs.

Otherwise the answer is a V followed by the `(k-P(n-1,m))`th permutation of `n` Hs and `m-1` Vs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Matt. I have yet to try out this approach. But I am guessing this will flow towards memoization technique using DP. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can implement it recursively or iteratively pretty much the way I said it.  There aren't any overlapping subproblems since since solving the problem only requires solving one smaller subproblem, and DP is not required.